# how to display unicode in html without javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, unicode

How do you display unicode character U+1F698, in the Transport And Map Symbols Block, in an html page preferably without using Javascript? I have found the following html scape secuence: `&#x1F698;` which, when included in an html page, shows the following square symbol 🚘, tested in chrome and firefox.

Comment: I can see an ONCOMING AUTOMOBILE character in the question, after the words “the following square symbol”. So the character is included correctly in the question; it just does not show when a user’s system has no font containing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [codepoints](http://codepoints.net/U+1F698) website appears to have a solution. They use the [Symbola font](http://zhm.github.io/symbola/) which is added to the page using `@font-face`, and that renders some unicode symbols correctly, including the one specified in your question.

`@font-face` include (for testing, don't actually link to codepoints stylesheet when in production, instead copy it locally and link there instead):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://codepoints.net/api/font-face/Symbola.css">
```

Displaying the character:

```
<span style="font-family: Symbola, serif;">&#x1F698;</span>
```

Comment: Symbola, like most fonts, renders *some* Unicode characters. It covers many symbols that most fonts don’t, but it is incorrect to assume that it contains all, or even most, Unicode characters.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Ok, agreed, I have edited the answer to better reflect that Symbola doesn't render all unicode.

Comment: Author of codepoints.net here. If you have a fixed set of characters, that you want to display within HTML, you can use [this technique](http://24ways.org/2011/creating-custom-font-stacks-with-unicode-range/) with specifically crafted fonts. On services like http://fontello.com/ you can drag 'n drop a custom icon font and also adapt codepoint-to-glyph mappings that is suited for this trick.

Comment: Also, by the way, *please do not hotlink to the given CSS file!* (Thanks jvperrin for pointing it out.) For one, it eats my bandwidth, but it will also soonish be, that I restructure the fonts, so it's likely that this will change. What's in the CSS file? Basically an [@font-face](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/) declaration, that links to the Symbola font files. You can download them at the link above and convert them to EOT, WOFF and other needed formats on [fontsquirrel.com](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator).

Answer (score 2):

You probably do not have a suitable font that can display this symbol, or the font you have set it to cannot display it.

You could check if you have a font that has that character [on this page](http://www.charbase.com/1f698-unicode-oncoming-automobile).

According to [this page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f698/fontsupport.htm), the only major font that supports this character is [Symbola](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/symbola/index.htm). <sub>(LastResort is [not a real font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19238140/how-to-display-unicode-in-html-without-javascript/19238205#comment28478048_19238205))</sub>

Comment: Browsers have fonts? Where did you install the fonts in your browser?

Comment: LastResort isn’t a real font but shows generic placeholder glyphs for characters. At present, Symbola seems to be the only font that supports U+1F698.